# How to do a draggable expandlble div (React, Tailwind)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, resize, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get something similar to what is on this page
This is from the Tailwind CSS [website](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-shrink#shrink), 
I'm interested in the sidegraber thingy that can shrink the parent div.
 So far i've been trying to use vanilla css 'resize' tag with:
`resize: horizontal;` 
`overflow: auto;`

but it didn't work great 

[image: Tailwind CSS picture]
Any tips? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually inspect the tailwind site to see its css, as it actually uses Tailwind :D[image]

You can see that the parent div is relative and it contains 2 divs, one empty, and one with the content. When you move the grabby thingy, you set a margin ot the empty div, and translate the grabby thingy the same amount to the left. In the example, i have dragged the thingy 55px to the left, so it translated it 55px to the left, and added a margin to the empty div (55px again).
You can calculate this pixel value by subtracting the current mouseX position from the Xposition when you first clicked and started dragging.

Comment: Thanks! Been looking at this chunk of html for a while, you helped a lot!

Comment: do you have any sample link?